# How to recover deleted partition?

Tags: partition, data-recovery, data-loss

I have accidently applied `CLEAN` command in `diskpart`. After that I have created new partitions and installed windows. Is there any way of recovering the lost data even after creating new partitions and installing new windows?

Please guide me. If you know any good software for recovery, kindly, let me know.

Comment: It's not possible.  If you  already installed the windows now.

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar.. if I use any recovery software is there any chance of recovery?

Comment: Bro you create the partition and then you installed the windows also .. so chance of recovery is .. not to be possible..  but you can try with software.  It's work for then it's your.. luck.. I will send you some software list.. just try it..

Comment: I post some advance software..  that works for you if it's possible then thank you !!

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar thanks alot for your time.. really appreciated

Comment: Your welcome... bro :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this software**

1.EaseUS data recovery software.
2. MiniTool Power Data Recovery 
3.Remo Partition Recovery software. 
4.https://winhowto.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/undo-diskpart-clean-recover-lost-disk-or-partition-in-windows-7/#comments
5.https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&q=how%20to%20recover%20the%20data%20after%20diskpart%20clean&spell=1&sa=X